# MySQL in VMWare Ubuntu 11.10 64bit, Configuration

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, python, innodb

Can anyone suggest an optimal setting for what I'm doing?  (Note that this is a one time job, after finishing my code, I'll put this back to development setting.)

I am setting up a 64bit Ubuntu 11.10 VM with 4 cores and 16GB RAM.  I'm going to import 15MM+ rows into a single table and upon saving, the Python/Django code will trigger a look up to a second table, and pull some fields from the second table and update the large table.

The job has already failed once because I was trying to import 15MM+ in one short.  So I have broken the file down into 16 files.

There will be some filtering and export off the first table after the import is completed.

The DB is InnoDB.  I don't know how good the default my-large or my-huge .cnf settings are  and not sure if it is suitable at all for me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://mysqltuner.com/ try this out

Answer (score 1):

try [this](http://tools.percona.com/wizard) or [this](https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl). both should give you some sane configuration values suitable for modern hardware.